# What does "May a Band of Nomadic Barbers Gang-Lather Your Sister" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "May a Band of Nomadic Barbers Gang-Lather Your Sister" mean?

I am reading an article about an American microbiologist Carl Woese at university of Illinois. It says that Woese liked to exchange letters with Dr Harry Noller at California. Some of these letters are rubber-stamped with Woese's favorite statement: "May a Band of Nomadic Barbers Gang-Lather Your Sister".

What does that sentence means?

I have found this sentence here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4008555/

Thank you very much

Comment: The true meaning is very probably an in-joke between Woese and Noller.

Comment: ... you wot m8?

Comment: Gang-Lather smacks of gang-bang, and not all that welcome either. *May a number of men **verb** your sister* cannot end well.

Comment: Which part of the sentence are you asking about, @fasligand? *Nomadic barber* should be readily understood, even if the purpose of mentioning them in particular might not be. *Gang-lather* is probably a unique collocation.

Comment: It is a joke. Barbers typically had/have barber shops and were not/are not nomads. Barbers use lather before shaving a man's beard. So, gang-lather means all the nomad (roving) barbers would put lather on someone's sister. Sisters and mothers are typically the object of insults across a host of macho settings, especially in Irish or Italian communities. So, this is like a take-off on a macho riff. There is an easy sexual translation of this. I assume Woese was creating an "in" group and that fake insult was directed at those who didn't agree with him, his "out" group.

Comment: There is also a history in English of saying things with that use of may (subjunctive, as it were): May the [person or group] [do] something to you. As in (Game of Thrones, for example), May the gods be with you. Or: May the force be with you (Star Wars).

Comment: @YosefBaskin - "May a number of men verb your sister cannot end well. " The verb could be _serenade_,  _admire_, _praise_, etc